# How to use parameters in a SQL query with NOT EXISTS?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, parameters

How can I change following query, so that I'm able to parameterize the `SparePartNames`?

It returns all ID's of repairs where not all mandatory spareparts were changed, in other words where at least one part is missing.

Note that the number of spareparts might change in future  not only the names. Is it possible without using a stored procedure with dynamic SQL? If not, how could this SP look like?

**Edit**: Note that i do not need to know how to pass a list/array as parameter, this is asked myriads of time on SO. I've also already a `Split` table-valued-function. I'm just wondering how i could rewrite the query to be able to join(or whatever) with a list of mandatory parts, so that i'll find all records where **at least one part** is missing. So is it possible to use a varchar-parameter like `'1264-3212,1254-2975'` instead of a list of `NOT EXISTS`? Sorry for the confusion if it was not clear in the first place.

```
SELECT  d.idData
FROM    tabData d
INNER JOIN modModel AS m ON d.fiModel = m.idModel 
WHERE  (m.ModelName = 'MT27I') 
AND (d.fiMaxServiceLevel >= 2) 
AND (d.Manufacture_Date < '20120511') 
AND (NOT EXISTS
      (SELECT NULL
        FROM  tabDataDetail AS td 
        INNER JOIN tabSparePart AS sp ON sp.idSparePart = td.fiSparePart
        WHERE (td.fiData = d.idData) 
        AND (sp.SparePartName = '1264-3212'))
    OR (NOT EXISTS
      (SELECT NULL
        FROM  tabDataDetail AS td 
        INNER JOIN tabSparePart AS sp ON sp.idSparePart = td.fiSparePart
        WHERE (td.fiData = d.idData) 
        AND (sp.SparePartName = '1254-2975'))
    )
)
```

Unfortunately I don't see how I could use `sp.SparePartName IN/NOT IN(@sparePartNames)` here.

Comment: Make one of your parameters a csv of sparepartnames. In the sql chop it up in a while loop and populate a temporary table, then you can use a join

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: Same problem, i need to find all records where **not all parts** were changed. When i would use a `JOIN`, i would find only records where **no parts** at all were changed(see [Steve's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10549652/284240)),  but maybe i'm wrong.

Comment: Hmm that's a different question, but the answer is NOT ALL. If you want those where some but not all, then it's Any and Not ALL. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189773

Comment: we all thought you were asking how to send in a list of spare part names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is (or will be) a table or view of mandatory spare parts, a list of exists can be replaced with a left join to tabDataDetail / tabSparePart pair on SparePartName; non-matches are reported back using `td.fiSparePart is null`.

```
; with mandatorySpareParts (SparePartName) as (
  select '1264-3212'
  union all
  select '1254-2975'
)
SELECT  d.idData
FROM    tabData d
INNER JOIN modModel AS m ON d.fiModel = m.idModel 
WHERE  (m.ModelName = 'MT27I') 
AND (d.fiMaxServiceLevel >= 2) 
AND (d.Manufacture_Date < '20120511') 
AND exists
(
  SELECT null
    from mandatorySpareParts msp
    left join ( tabDataDetail AS td 
                INNER JOIN tabSparePart AS sp 
                   ON sp.idSparePart = td.fiSparePart 
                  AND td.fiData = d.idData
              )
      ON msp.SparePartName = sp.SparePartName
   WHERE td.fiSparePart is null
)
```

Part names should be replaced by their id's, which would simplify left join and speed the query up.

EDIT: i've errorneously left filtering of td in where clause, which invalidated left join. It is now in ON clause where it belongs.

Comment: Thanks. But actually i want to pass the list as parameter. That's why i've asked the question. But maybe it would be better to use a view instead. I'll wait for other reponse until i'll accept this since it's not the answer of the question ;)

Comment: Using @steve 's dbo.Split function, you might replace `mandatorySpareParts' with `dbo.Split(',', '1264-3212,1254-2975') as mandatorySpareParts`.

Comment: Thanks again. Your apporoach looks pretty well, in combination with `Split` it would answer my question. But unfortunately it does not return the correct result. Actually it always returns nothing(and i've checked that it should). I assume that `td.fiSparePart is null` is never true.

Comment: I've errorneously left filtering of td in where clause, which invalidated left join. It is now in ON clause where it belongs. Please try again.

Comment: Thanks a ton, that's working. I'll use `dbo.Split`(as Steve has suggested) to pass a varchar parameter with all sparepart names. Performance is not a key factor since it is a background task, readability has priority so i keep the names instead of the ID's. There's a unique index on `SparePartName` anyway.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to create a function to split delimited strings:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split] 
(
    @Delimiter char(1), 
    @StringToSplit varchar(512)
)
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN 
(
    WITH Pieces(pieceNumber, startIndex, delimiterIndex) 
    AS 
    (
        SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @StringToSplit)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT pieceNumber + 1, delimiterIndex + 1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @StringToSplit, delimiterIndex + 1)
        FROM Pieces
        WHERE delimiterIndex > 0
    )
    SELECT 
        SUBSTRING(@StringToSplit, startIndex, CASE WHEN delimiterIndex > 0 THEN delimiterIndex - startIndex ELSE 512 END) AS Value
    FROM Pieces
)
```

populate a table variable with the spare part names:

```
DECLARE @SpareParts TABLE
(
    SparePartName varchar(50) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
);

INSERT INTO @SpareParts
SELECT Value FROM dbo.Split(',', '1264-3212,1254-2975');
```

and then join to the table variable:

```
SELECT  d.idData
FROM    tabData d
INNER JOIN modModel AS m ON d.fiModel = m.idModel 
WHERE  (m.ModelName = 'MT27I') 
AND (d.fiMaxServiceLevel >= 2) 
AND (d.Manufacture_Date < '20120511') 
AND EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM  tabDataDetail AS td 
        INNER JOIN tabSparePart AS sp ON sp.idSparePart = td.fiSparePart
        LEFT JOIN @SpareParts AS s ON s.SparePartName = sp.SparePartName
        WHERE td.fiData = d.idData
            AND s.SparePartName IS NULL
    )
```

Comment: Thanks. But this does not return the correct result. I need to find all records where not **all parts** were changed. You query returns only records where **no parts** were changed.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I understand your data correctly. Do you want all records where 1264-3212 or 1254-2975 were changed but not where both of them were changed?

Comment: No, i want all records where at least one part is missing.

Comment: I'm afraid that it returns all records where any of the spartparts were changed. Not only the records where one is missing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and the valuable answer. I've accepted Nikola's approach though which is similar and works(now). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Use a table-variable and join on that.

Comment: Thanks. How would i do that? Maybe you're approach is similar to [Steve's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10549652/284240). Then it would return the wrong result(see the comment there). But maybe i've misunderstood you.

Comment: I suppose you need to do a count on the number of spare parts and compare it to a count of parts changed. 0 < count(spare parts) < count(all parts)